# Altium : How to connect pads of an F antenna

Tags: altium, ground-plane, pcb-antenna, copper-pour

I'm designing a reverse F antenna. It is connected to ground and the antenna line.

It is built of several place fill with small overlaps.
To do this, I declared the component as a net tie. The package exposes 2 ground pads and one antenna pad (called 0 on the pictures).

[image]

Now I'm facing an issue while placing it on the pcb :

I designed a ground plane around the antenna line and set the clearance rule 
for this net in order to get the correct impedance.

Problems :

- The ground plane is poured against the ground plane of the antenna.

[image]

- I tried to connect the ground plane and the ground pins of the antenna but
  I'm not allowed to do this. I suspect that altium assumes that there the whole antenna is connected to antenna line and therefore does not allow to reach the ground pad.

[image]

Do you have any idea on how to solve this issue ?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post 3 pictures, so here is the third which illustrates the connection issue : http://i.stack.imgur.com/zusop.png

Comment: Can you make the pads bigger (and possiblly rectangular rather than round) so that they reach to the edge of the component? if so does that help you hook them up?

Comment: Make an exception in the clearance rule saying "where the first object matches 'InPolygon('myGroundPolygon')' and where the second object matches 'InComponent('myAntenna')'", or something like that. Without seeing it, it's difficult to say for sure how it needs to be set up

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

Make an exception for the antenna, so the ground plane will connect to it.